# Transform a mesh of quads and triangles into a mesh composed of only triangles

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I do not know how to explain my problem well comprehensively. So I'll show you an example ...

I have this array indicating the vertices indices for each quad or triangle:

```
>>> faces
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 7, 6, 5],
       [0, 4, 1, 0],
       [1, 5, 6, 2],
       [2, 6, 7, 3],
       [4, 0, 3, 7],
       [1, 4, 5, 0]])
```

Triangles are the elements that end with `0`

I want to make a transformation like this:

```
>>> faces
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],  #->[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3],
       [4, 7, 6, 5],  #-> [4, 7, 6], [4, 6, 5],
       [0, 4, 1, 0],  #-> [0, 4, 1],
       [1, 5, 6, 2],  #-> [1, 5, 6], [1, 6, 2],
       [2, 6, 7, 3],  #-> [2, 6, 7], [2, 7, 3],
       [4, 0, 3, 7],  #-> [4, 0, 3], [4, 3, 7],
       [1, 4, 5, 0]]) #-> [1, 4, 5]]
```

So how can I make this transformation efficiently?

I did a function that solves it differently. Place the tirangles obtained by the quads at the end of the array.

```
def v_raw_to_tris(tessfaces):
    len_tessfaces = len(tessfaces)
    quad_indices = tessfaces[:, 3].nonzero()[0]
    t3 = np.empty(((len_tessfaces + len(quad_indices)), 3), 'i4')

    t3[:len_tessfaces] = tessfaces[:, :3]
    t3[len_tessfaces:] = tessfaces[quad_indices][:, (0, 2, 3)]

    return t3
```

But I don't want the resulting triangles to be at the end of the array. And yes in front of the original quads

Comment: So, the output would have variable number of lists, e.g. first elem would have two lists?

Comment: Or can we put all of them in rows, giving us a total of 12 rows?

Comment: @Divakar, nope. Each element would have 3 items

Comment: Let me put it in another way - What must be the shape of output array?

Comment: The shape would be (-1, 3). In the example would be (12, 3)

Comment: Seems like your solution is close to optimal; what does 'I do not want it to end' mean?

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn, I don't want the resulting triangles to be at the end of the array. And yes in front of the original quads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could replicate each row with the one-off shifting for each row as two rows and mask out the triangular ones at the end. The implementation would look something like this -

```
def transform1(a):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a[:,-1] == 0)
    out0 = np.empty((a.shape[0],2,3),dtype=a.dtype)      

    out0[:,0,1:] = a[:,1:-1]
    out0[:,1,1:] = a[:,2:]

    out0[...,0] = a[:,0,None]

    out0.shape = (-1,3)

    mask = np.ones(out0.shape[0],dtype=bool)
    mask[idx*2+1] = 0
    return out0[mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [94]: a
Out[94]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 7, 6, 5],
       [0, 4, 1, 0],
       [1, 5, 6, 2],
       [2, 6, 7, 3],
       [4, 0, 3, 7],
       [1, 4, 5, 0]])

In [95]: transform1(a)
Out[95]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [4, 7, 6],
       [4, 6, 5],
       [0, 4, 1],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [1, 6, 2],
       [2, 6, 7],
       [2, 7, 3],
       [4, 0, 3],
       [4, 3, 7],
       [1, 4, 5]])
```

**Possible improvement**

We can introduce [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) to replace the two step assignments for `out0[:,0,1:]` and `out0[:,1,1:]` as one and that hopefully should improve it, like so -

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
def strided_axis1(a, L):
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    nL = n-L+1
    return as_strided(a, (m,nL,L),(s0,s1,s1))

def transform2(a):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a[:,-1] == 0)
    out0 = np.empty((a.shape[0],2,3),dtype=a.dtype)    
    out0[...,1:] = strided_axis1(a[:,1:], 2)    
    out0[...,0] = a[:,0,None]
    out0.shape = (-1,3)
    mask = np.ones(out0.shape[0],dtype=bool)
    mask[idx*2+1] = 0
    return out0[mask]
```

Comment: I did a benchmark in an extremely dense mesh with the function of my example `v_raw_to_tris` and the `transform1` and `transform2`. The result was `0.056070998899599545, 0.05587086547734543, 0.06008279023626528`. The `transform1` function seems to be the winner. I'll test the results

Comment: Cool that you are benchmarking. What does my solution do in terms of speed?

Comment: @Mano-Wii Hmm that's really marginal improvement, which makes sense I guess given that you are already using efficient tools with your original method.

Comment: @Mano-Wii Also the original method was doing a simplified task of assigning the triangles at the end and hence not exactly doing what was desired. So, I think that's not fair on the proposed methods for runtime comparison :)

Comment: @Chiel, Your solution took 11.60 seconds! -> here was how I did it to test ->  https://hastebin.com/irupopedal.py

Comment: @Mano-Wii 11.6 compared to the numbers you wrote before?! Yikes.

Comment: @Chiel, yes :\ Apparently your solution is not very efficient

Comment: @Mano-Wii. Interesting. I have edited your script and generate a random `np` array with the proper dimensions. Your first method does not work with your script, but the others do.

Comment: @Mano-Wii. I managed to get my algorithm at the same order of magnitude as the others (see below). The array handling is now one line shorter than the `transform1` loop above. Masking is slightly cheaper than deletion, but under some conditions deletion might be desired. Thanks for the benchmarking.

Comment: @Chiel, It was much more efficient than the previous one. the time now was `0.0885`. while the `trasnform1` and` transform2` functions gave, respectively, `0.0623`, `0.0700` in the same mesh.

Answer (score 0):

This works with a fairly compact code. First, we split all the quads into triangles, and subsequently, we delete all the second elements from those quads that already were triangles. Deletion after splitting keeps the algorithm simple.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [4, 7, 6, 5],
              [0, 4, 1, 0],
              [1, 5, 6, 2],
              [2, 6, 7, 3],
              [4, 0, 3, 7],
              [1, 4, 5, 0]])

b = np.empty((a.shape[0], 2, 3))
b[:,0,:] = a[:,(0,1,2)]
b[:,1,:] = a[:,(0,2,3)]
b.shape = (-1, 3)

idx_to_delete = 2*np.flatnonzero(a[:,-1] == 0)+1
b = np.delete(b, idx_to_delete, axis=0)
```

The output is:

```
In [4]: print(b)
   [[ 0.  1.  2.]
    [ 0.  2.  3.]
    [ 4.  7.  6.]
    [ 4.  6.  5.]
    [ 0.  4.  1.]
    [ 1.  5.  6.]
    [ 1.  6.  2.]
    [ 2.  6.  7.]
    [ 2.  7.  3.]
    [ 4.  0.  3.]
    [ 4.  3.  7.]
    [ 1.  4.  5.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler alternative is

```py
import numpy as np

def quad2tri(mesh):
    if mesh.shape[1] != 4:
        raise ValueError("mesh is not quadrilateral.")
    reduced_mesh = np.zeros([2*mesh.shape[0], 3])
    reduced_mesh[::2] = mesh[:,[0,1,2]]
    reduced_mesh[1::2] = mesh[:,[0,2,3]]
    return reduced_mesh

mesh = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [4, 7, 6, 5],
              [0, 4, 1, 0],
              [1, 5, 6, 2],
              [2, 6, 7, 3],
              [4, 0, 3, 7],
              [1, 4, 5, 0]])

print(quad2tri(mesh))
```

Outputs

```py
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 2. 3.]
 [4. 7. 6.]
 [4. 6. 5.]
 [0. 4. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 5. 6.]
 [1. 6. 2.]
 [2. 6. 7.]
 [2. 7. 3.]
 [4. 0. 3.]
 [4. 3. 7.]
 [1. 4. 5.]
 [1. 5. 0.]]
```